# mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask); not pausing the handler

Tags: java, android, android-handler

so I want to start a time counter and pause it on activity and on some button click and resume it from time where pause it, so as you see below I am showing it in textview in every second, so when I press pause button with mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask); then it stops updating text view, looks like handler stops but when restarted then it looks like it did not stopped, eg- if I stop it at 2 seconds then it shows 2 seconds in text view and I start it after 5 seconds then it shows 7 seconds in text view but it should start from 2 seconds, where I stopped it.so please help me to fix it, what I am doing wrong and what to do

```
 public View onCreateView(){
 if(mStartTime==0L){
            mStartTime= SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask,100);
        }
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final long start = mStartTime;
            long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            text3.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
            mHandler.postAtTime(this,
                    start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
        }
    };


 public void onPause() {
 mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

public void onResume() {
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); 
}
```

Comment: Is this code runnable on its own? I don't think it is. Please include necessary code so others can run it on their machine and spot the problem. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27005014).

Comment: yes, it is run runnable.

Comment: Where is the main method then?